# Test if String is JSON without actually deseriazing / inserting data

Tags: apex, json

I want to find out if a given String "would" be deserializable without actually doing it. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: What about creating a regEx to check conformity to standards? tbh if you're going to the effort of checking with regEx then I'd probably just plump for trying to deserialize. Discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Comment: regex can easily run into SFDC's 'regex too complicated' error; I agree with Richard on just using the try-catch method to see if it is malformed

Answer (score -1):

```
Boolean isValidJSON = false;
String message = '{"response":"Some json"}';
try{
    Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(message);
    isValidJSON = true;
}catch(JSONException e){
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
}
System.debug(isValidJSON);
```

Comment: Hey, Вадим Пуцык, you're doing exactly what Robert Sösemann asked us not to do ;-)